# Understanding a LINQ query - orderby ascending

Tags: c#, linq

I don't understand why code A is correct and code B is incorrect:

code A

```
IEnumerable<decimal> loanQuery = 
from amount in loanAmounts
where amount % 2 == 0
orderby amount 
select ascending amount //this line
```

code B (incorrect)

```
IEnumerable<decimal> loanQuery = 
from amount in loanAmounts
where amount % 2 == 0
select amount 
orderby ascending amount
```

As a lot of people have answered have been incorrect, I have now posted the correct code:

```
IEnumerable<decimal> loanQuery = 
from amount in loanAmounts
where amount % 2 == 0
orderby amount ascending
select amount
```

Comment: Because you need to finish the query with a select.

Comment: there is something called syntax in the programming language

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb397678.aspx

Comment: If you learnt Linq basics you should have understood this, I suggest you to read a tutorial/book about Linq, 10 pages later you'll understand why it is incorrect.

Comment: Both codes are incorrect, cause `ascending` is an invalid expression term after `select`.

Comment: @Meds Well the correct answer wasn't either of them so I guess we were all wrong there. Maybe pick up a book about Linq as well?

Comment: Yes, of course.. Everyone was wrong. By the way, they didn't say that your first example was correct, please click on @Freelancer link, and take a look at the first example (Query #2).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a LINQ-Query IS NOT a SQL-Query and so has its own Syntax rules. You have to follow the order:

```
FROM     
WHERE      
ORDER BY     
SELECT      
GROUP BY
```

Its the same Reason why you cannot write the SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT * WHERE i=2 FROM tableName
```

but have to write

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE i=2
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I must have missed that in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

In short: it's required by the syntax. See Microsoft documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384065.aspx)

> A query expression must begin with a from clause and must end with a
>   select or group clause.

Answer (score 2):

[From MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384065.aspx), you see what is right order for the keywords

> A query expression must begin with a from clause and must end with a
>   select or group clause. Between the first from clause and the last
>   select or group clause, it can contain one or more of these optional
>   clauses: where, orderby, join, let and even additional from clauses.
>   You can also use the into keyword to enable the result of a join or
>   group clause to serve as the source for additional query clauses in
>   the same query expression.